# Installing R error

Tags: 16.04, r

I've installed R in ubuntu 16.04.6 following this [tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/updating-r-on-ubuntu/) It seems Its correctly installed in

> /usr/lib/R/bin/R

but It does not open when I just type

```
R
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?  If `/usr/lib/R/bin/` is not in your path or a link is not setup to `/usr/lib/R/bin/R` just typing in `R` will not work.

Comment: You should update your $PATH

Comment: Im pretty new to all this, how do I update my path?

Comment: It should have installed a "shell wrapper" at `/usr/bin/R` - which lets it work using standard paths

Answer (score 2):

So I just copied

```
cp /usr/lib/R/bin/R  /usr/bin/
```

And it seems to work